# Why is html canvas botching this source image?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm toying around with making a super simple HTML Canvas crop tool. The first thing I tested was to see if the output image would be perceptually identical to the input image.

Using [this image](http://paulbourke.net/dome/testpattern/1024.png) as a source, canvas fails to maintain the smooth gradients as you can see in the image comparison I posted here (still visible despite the imgur compression). You can also replicate it in any online photo editor such as https://pixlr.com.

Is there some way to fix this?

[image: Left: Original, Right: After Canvas]

Code snippet I am using:

```js
const loadImageToCanvas = (file) => { // file is from input.files
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
        const { width, height } = img;
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
};
```

Comment: Why not just use a canvas to display the original image too? Perhaps it's as simple as Same_output_element_type + same_scale = same_result?

Comment: Displaying the original image also shows incorrectly.

Comment: Both images appear identically here. What IS different, is the way the browser renders them *when they're resized* Shown at 100% scale, each output element had a screenshot taken. A layer1 - layer2 difference operation on the two images results in a black picture - no difference. The browser messes this up (here) at zoom levels of less than 50% (50 is still fine) At 33% zoom, the image element render white lines as grey, while the canvas continues to reproduce them faithfully. old i7, built-in graphics, x64 windows 7 with Chrome. Ha ha, the rabbit hole deepens...

Comment: Without compression: https://u.cubeupload.com/sean256/colorspacepngfail.png as you can see there is a difference. Even with the imgur compression above I can visually see a difference, so I don't know how you got a solid black picture from a difference blend.

Comment: Nice catch. It looked the same to me at a 50% zoom, but you've clearly shown that the browser gets that wrong too. You get the right result when each element is shown at 1024x1024, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Two words: *gamma correction*.  Your PNG file has a gAMA chunk of 1.0000.  Web browsers are (correctly) using this information to adjust the displayed pixels for an output device having the standard sRGB gamma of 2.2.  This behaviour is the same for both <canvas> and <img> elements.[1]

I don't know what viewer or conversion tool you are using to produce your imgur image, but it is either stripping or ignoring the gamma chunk.

If your image is in fact encoded with a gamma of 2.2 (and thus the gamma chunk is erroneous), you can remove the chunk with:

`pngcrush -rem gAMA 1024.png 1024.nogamma.png`

---

[1] The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#colour-spaces-and-colour-correction) mandates this consistency.  Are you really seeing different behaviour between your (correct, although using `createObjectURL` is unnecessary and a bad idea) code and an <img> tag?

Comment: Here is an uncompressed comparison I made in PS with a difference blend output: https://u.cubeupload.com/sean256/colorspacepngfail.png Both the canvas render AND an <img> tag render show this image as incorrect. In PS, and MacOS Preview the image looks correct.